# Undefiend result during console

Tags: javascript

Here in my below JS code I am getting 2 answers for single console, first one is expected answer and another one is `undefined`.

I didn't understand why am getting second `undefined`, can anyone tell me the reason.

```js
function sayHello2(name) {
    var text = 'Hello ' + name;
    var say = function() {
        console.log(text);
    }
    return say;
}
var say2 = new sayHello2('Bob');
console.log(say2());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything from inner function. If nothing is retruned from a function then by deault `undefined` is returned. You have to return `text` from inner function:

```
return text;
```

```js
function sayHello2(name) {
  var text = 'Hello ' + name;
  var say = function() 
  { 
    console.log(text); 
    return text;
  }
  return say;
}
var say2 = new sayHello2('Bob');
console.log(say2());
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(say2());`  logs the result of `say2`.

And as `say2` does not return anything the result is `undefined`

If you want to return anything from `say2` you might want to write:

```
var say = function() 
{ 
  console.log(text);
  return text
}
```

But it's not clear why you use `new` in this case at all.

```js
function sayHello2(name) {
  var text = 'Hello ' + name;
  var say = function() {
    console.log(text);
    return text
  }
  return say;
}

var say2 = sayHello2('Bob');
console.log(say2());
```

Answer (score -1):

say2() is returning a function. It should also return some data.